# Data gets corrupted when notifyDataSetChanged() is called

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `Recyclerview`, six items in a grid layoutl. I have a listener for onClick, when the user clicks on the item, the item's thumbnail goes grey.

Model includes getters and setters. Activity includes dump data for simulation. Adapter checks for the new thumbnail, if it contains a specific string, it updates the thumbnail.

Problem: When i do a for loop to hide all the items, the last item (last index) goes grey, and the data is decreased by one.

That means, the item in `0` index, is out, and the item in `1` index, is now in `0`. So every item is taking his next item place, and only the last item has changed.

Model:

```
private int id;
private String Title;
private String Thumbnail;
private String HiddenThumbnail;
private String Sound;
private String spelling_sound;
private int type;
private String extra;
private String hiddentext;

public GameItem(int id, String title, String thumbnail, String sound, String spelling_sound, int mType, String mExtra){
    setId(id);
    setTitle(title);
    setThumbnail(thumbnail);
    setHiddenThumbnail(thumbnail);
    setSound(sound);
    setSpelling_sound(spelling_sound);
    setType(mType);
    setExtra(mExtra);
    setHiddentext(mExtra);
}
```

Adapter:

```
 if(mThumb.contains("#FFC4C4C4"))
{holder.mCard.setCardBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_hidden));}
```

Hiding Items:

```
    private void HideItems() {
    for(int i = 0; i < Items.size(); i++){
        Items.get(i).setThumbnail("#FFC4C4C4");
        Items.get(i).setExtra("");
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: in which file->class->method you are calling HideItems()?

Comment: I'm calling this method in the Activity.

Comment: you need to update the items of adapter also.

Comment: I guess i'm already doing that by calling notidyDataSetChanged(), if not please provide an example.

Comment: calling just notify the recyclerview to update its view from the data set. You need to change the data set you passed to adapter while initialising.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void HideItems() {
for(int i = 0; i < Items.size(); i++){
    mAdapter.itemList.get(i).setThumbnail("#FFC4C4C4");
    mAdapter.itemList.get(i).setExtra("");
}
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Make sure the Items are public in adapter.

Comment: still the same issue.

Comment: Before hiding: http://i.imgur.com/ZEuOFLW.png, after: http://i.imgur.com/T4d7Ad6.png

Comment: what kind of object is Items. Where are you initialising it?

Comment: I guess the problem is where you are calling the method. Need to see the whole files(Activity,Adapter)

Comment: In the Activity, i'm creating a List<GameItem> with 'Items' name and adding some dump data (for example animals pics)

Comment: Adapter: https://paste.ofcode.org/yCq6BWuQczYaGzNPLCr6Eq - Activity: https://paste.ofcode.org/mpdCB4uGKhfjwcCNmKfsqt

Comment: In adapter class, you are setting views from List<GameItem> gotten from activity or creating in  your adapter class from some database or so?

Comment: Ok. got the files. Seeing

Comment: Try now. edited the answer. Did it solve your problem. Let me know.

Comment: Same problem, no idea why its happening like this.